# android styles.xml no resource found that matches the given name of: attr

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

I downloaded this project to work on and it has a lot of errors. It's for an alarm application. It doesn't create the R file because of the errors either. I have seen a working build but I don't have code that compiles because of these errors. I thought it was a dependency issue but I can't seem to figure it out. The manifest file minSdk=14 and TargetSdk = 19 then the properties is target: android-19. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
```

Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

```
-->

<style name="PreferencesTheme">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
```

Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
backward-compatibility can go here.

```
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/appBgColor</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/rounded_vertical_scroll_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal">@drawable/rounded_vertical_scroll_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">insideOverlay</item>
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="switch_dark">
    <item name="track">@drawable/switch_track_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="thumb">@drawable/switch_inner_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textOn">@string/textOn</item>
    <item name="textOff">@string/textOff</item>
    <item name="thumbTextPadding">12dip</item>
    <item name="switchMinWidth">96dip</item>
    <item name="switchPadding">16dip</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="textColorHighlight">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="textColorHint">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="textColorLink">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<!-- For Normal Text Size -->
<style name="normalTextSize" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<!-- For Normal Text Size  With Bold -->
<style name="normalTextSizeWithBold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<!-- For Medium Text Size -->
<style name="mediumTextSize" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<!-- For Medium Text Size With Bold -->
<style name="mediumTextSizeWidthBold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<!-- For Large Text Size -->
<style name="largeTextSize" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<!-- For Large Text Size With Bold -->
<style name="largeTextSizeWithBold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<!-- For Custom Dialog -->

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_dialog</item>
</style>

<!-- Animation for dialog box -->
<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="MyHolo" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPreferencesTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/appBgColor</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/appBgColor</item>
</style>
```

Here are the errors:

C:\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(38, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'switchStyle'.

Error:(53, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'.

Error:(54, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorHighlight'.

Error:(55, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorHint'.
Error:(56, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorLink'.

Error:(57, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textSize'.

Error:(47, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'switchMinWidth'.

Error:(48, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'switchPadding'.

Error:(49, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'switchTextAppearance'.

Error:(45, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textOff'.

Error:(44, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textOn'.

Error:(43, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'thumb'.

Error:(46, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'thumbTextPadding'.

Error:(34, 88) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'track'.

Answer (score 2):

Name of resourse should be

```
<item name="android:textColor">...</item>
```

You miss `android:` part for all problematic resources

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with different resources missing.
In my case, I was missing SDK that one of the AppCompat support library needed.

Check you build configuration and check that you have installed every SDK that they are referencing.

This is because, event if they can work on lower API's during build they use resources from the same SDK that the library version you use. 
For example, if you use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0 and you plan to run your app on Kitkat (19) to build it you would need to have Lollipop SDK.

Comment: alright i'll check this out and see if it works out. Thanks for the reply

Comment: still isn't working. I downloaded all of Lollipop sdk.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file? Or at least dependency part.

Comment: `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Android Projects:SwitchCompatLibrary-master:SwitchCompatLibrary')
    compile project(':Android Projects:New folder')
    compile project(':eclipse:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }`

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: comment out all the issues with resources and see if it will give you another issue with dependencies or something. I run into that quite a bit with importing eclipse projects

Comment: have you fix this issue?